# d3.js stacked barchart not drawing along x axis?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm stumped on this one, I need another set of eyes to help me see what I'm missing. I have a bl.ock up here:

http://bl.ocks.org/hepplerj/c419baa3abf7363cd2d5

As you'll see, a few of the `rect` elements aren't drawing along the x axis correctly. Any pointers on what I'm overlooking? Much appreciated!

Comment: Someone downvoted my comment for some reason. The issue is the height_scale variable. The range is inverted. So the SVG is drawing from the uppermost left.

Comment: @Incodeveritas, your answer seemed like a fine answer to me.  I don't understand why it was downvoted.  It takes some effort to apply your answer (I didn't succeed after a couple of quick tries), but whoever downvoted it should at least have the courtesy to explain what was wrong with your answer.

Comment: I think it's more complicated, though.  `height_scale` is affecting each piece of a bar individually.

Comment: It was odd. Did you try just inserting the code I provided? It should have fixed the problem.

Comment: Also, in the future, post your code inside a fddle so we can test.

Comment: @Incodeveritas Not sure why you were downvoted, either. FWIW, that doesn't solve the problem. Mars is right that heigh_scale affects each bar individually.

I'll see about getting it on fiddle quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's just a minor issue with your code. First of all, here's a fiddle that's the same as your bl.ock: http://jsfiddle.net/gp2ex7fw/

View source and count the `<g class="bar">` elements, and you'll see that there are only seven, whereas you have data for eight grains. `millet/sorghum groats` is missing altogether. This creates gaps in each bar, resulting in the bar not filling up the entire height.

This is because of the following part of your code:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll("g")
    .data(stackLayout(stackData))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
```

When you do `selectAll("g")`, you're also selecting the first `g` element (used for transformation) that was attached to your `svg` element earlier.

The fix is very easy. Just change the above code to:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll(".bar")
    .data(stackLayout(stackData))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
```

Now we're only selecting `g` elements with `class="bar"` and not missing any data. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gp2ex7fw/1/